# chart.js pie chart - how to update dataset with smooth transition

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I have a chart.js pie chart.  When I update the dataset, I want the pie segments to adjust size smoothly to the new values (i.e. grow/shrink in size).

The pie chart does the rotate transition every time. I can turn off the rotate transition with .update('none') after setting the new data, but then the pie chart instantly changes with no transition.

Is there a way to do this?

My pie chart setup code is:

```
chartRegion_Emissions_ANZIC_BreakdownChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        options: {  
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            return tooltipItem.label + ': ' + addCommas(tooltipItem.raw) + 'kt';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        },
        data: {
            labels: [],
            datasets: []
        }
    });
```

and the update code (after AJAX request) is ...

```
chartRegion_Emissions_ANZIC_BreakdownChart.data.labels = data.labels;
                chartRegion_Emissions_ANZIC_BreakdownChart.data.datasets[0] = data.data[0];
                chartRegion_Emissions_ANZIC_BreakdownChart.update();//'none');
```

I'm using chart.js version 3.3.2... thanks for any help

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You override the entire dataset, if you instead of doing that only change the data of that dataset it will shrink/expand the segments of the data.

Example:

```js
const options = {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {}
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
const chart = new Chart(ctx, options);

document.getElementById('update').addEventListener('click', () => {
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = [10, 5, 12, 6, 8, 2];
  chart.update();
})
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <button id="update">
      update data
    </button>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.4.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Lee, I'll give that a go